# can't install using yum in RHEL 7.1

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rhel, rhel7

I got a RHEL 7.1 instance on amazon aws, now i am trying to install softwares using yum, but even very common softwares aren't available.

For example,

`$ sudo yum install lynx`

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb
No package lynx available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I am new to linux and `yum`. What's to be done so I can install softwares easily using `yum`.

Should I be adding repos?

Here, I tried doing what's said here -> [Top 5 Yum Repositories for CentOS/RHEL 7/6/5 and Fedora](http://tecadmin.net/top-5-yum-repositories-for-centos-rhel-systems/), and here -> [Install RepoForge (RPMForge) Repository On RHEL, CentOS, Scientific Linux 7/6.x/5.x/4.x](http://www.unixmen.com/install-repoforge-rpmforge-repository-rhel-centos-scientific-linux-76-x5-x4-x/) but to no use.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to search whether the repo is present by using 
     " yum search lynx"

Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb
================================ Matched: lynx =================================================================
pinfo.x86_64 : An info file viewer

For example
    "yum search httpd" shows

1. httpd.x86_64 : Apache HTTP Server httpd-devel.x86_64 : Development
   interfaces for the Apache HTTP server httpd-manual.noarch :
   Documentation for the Apache HTTP server.
2. httpd-tools.x86_64 : Tools
   for use with the Apache HTTP Server
3. List item libmicrohttpd.i686 : Lightweight
   library for embedding a webserver in applications
4. libmicrohttpd.x86_64 : Lightweight library for embedding a webserver
   in applications
5. mod_auth_mellon.x86_64 : A SAML 2.0 authentication
   module for the Apache Httpd Server mod_dav_svn.x86_64 : Apache httpd
   module for Subversion server

then check the output it gives you. By taking the output data we need to install any softwares using yum.

Now use

1. List item

   yum install "package name"

Answer (score 1):

Lynx is in *optional* repo. Check enabled repos with:

```
yum repolist all
```

Enable *optional* (using Oracle Linux as example):

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable ol7_optional_latest
```

Lynx should be installed now without problems:

```
sudo yum install lynx
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for this comment. The command used was:


$ yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional