# RH 7.1 Linux, yum install issue

Tags: linux, package, yum, rhel7

The Host is registered with Redhat, when I try yum install it says

> There are no enabled repos

How to enable repos.

There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097627/cant-install-using-yum-in-rhel-7-1) which is unanswered.

```
[root@# yum install pdksh.x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

Comment: `yum repolist all` what's the output ?

Comment: []# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
repolist: 0

Comment: have you set enabled=1 in repo file? and provide the output of "yum repolist all" and "yum list".

Comment: [root@l yum.repos.d]# pwd
/etc/yum.repos.d

Comment: [root@ yum.repos.d]# cat redhat.repo
#
# Certificate-Based Repositories
# Managed by (rhsm) subscription-manager
#
# *** This file is auto-generated.  Changes made here will be over-written. ***
# *** Use "subscription-manager repo-override --help" if you wish to make changes. ***
#
# If this file is empty and this system is subscribed consider
# a "yum repolist" to refresh available repos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your subscription related issue please follow this.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273

And regarding your pdksh installation, Pdksh was an open source version that had many of the ksh'88 shell features, which was only available for commercial Linux system and licensed by AT&T. Starting with RHEL 6, pdksh has been deprecated. If you need the Korn shell, use the standard public domain ksh (ksh'93)

```
yum install ksh
```

Hope this helps